# Silverlight ObservableCollection dependency properties are not updated in design mode

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, observablecollection

I use a dependency property of type `ObservableCollection<>` in my control. I want to automatically change content display in my control while editing `XAML` code. I write such a code:

```
public class RowInfoCollection : ObservableCollection<RowInfo>
{
}

//... here my control class
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowDataProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowData", typeof(RowInfoCollection), typeof(VisiGrid), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new RowInfoCollection(), RowDataChangedCallback));

    public RowInfoCollection RowData
    {
        get
        {
            return (RowInfoCollection)base.GetValue(RowDataProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(RowDataProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void RowDataChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisiGrid vg = d as VisiGrid;
        vg.rowData = (RowInfoCollection)e.NewValue;
        vg.rowData.CollectionChanged += vg.rowData_CollectionChanged;
        // Some application specific logic skipped
    }

    void rowData_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        rowData = RowData;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            // Skipped
        }
    }
```

When in run time, everything works ok. But when I change the property value in VS2010 designer there are some problems. When I completely remove value or insert it instead of empty VS' designer successfully refreshes display of my control. But when I add or remove collection items one at a time there's no change. When I build project the display updates (in fact, the designer reloads).

When I looked under debugger I saw that when in design mode it successfully calls my callback function when the collection is totally removed or inserted but does not fire `CollectionChanges` event when it is changed partially.

How should I force VS designer to track collection changes and fire events?

Thank you.

Comment: Noticed such a thing when looked into my control in design mode through a debugger. As mentioned earlier when I totally delete, insert or replace my collection that fires callback function. In all that cases argument property e.OldValue always has 0 items. May be problem is that VS designer does not keep collection between display refreshings? Or does it re-create control in cases when its attribute totally changes but not partially?

Comment: One more note. When I delete a collection item with a collection editor of the properties window it raises CollectionChanged event. Then data are removed from control correctly. When I add item using the same tool it calls my callback function which replaces previous collection (now it's not zero-sized) with new, containing one more item. The item is added into control but it's properties are not displayed though it contans some default data. Is there any description to read on how VS2010 Silverlight XAML editor deals with collections?